# Yii get table name by foreign key

Tags: mysql, yii

I have 2 tables: 
**City** -> ID, Name, Country_id 
**Countries** -> ID, Name

Is it possible to get the name of the "Countries" table 
from Country_id (Country_id is set a foreign key of course)?

Comment: what do you mean by "the name of the Countries" table?  do you mean the "name" field from Countries table or ?

Comment: Are `City` and `Countries` AR classes? If so is the relation between them in either of their `relations` methods?

Comment: I mean I want to create a new object named "Country" and I want to get the name of the object by the field "country_id" ,or is there a better way of doing that (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CActiveRecord::tableName()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#tableName-detail) might be what you're looking for.

Assuming City and Country are both AR classes *and* you have relations setup between the two of them.

```
$countryTableName = City::model()->findByPk($id)->country->tableName();
```

Comment: your solutions works, though I solved it with this small function https://gist.github.com/kidsil/4973878